# WebSphere Liberty on OpenShift

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, websphere-liberty

I would like to know if WebSphere liberty (WL) adds value when running on OpenShift using the SpringBoot framework.

As far as I can tell, WL offers supporting services that OpenShift also offers, like orchestration, service discovery, resource management, log aggregation, network management, etc.

We have already decided to use OpenShift and need to decide if we need Liberty at all and why, or develop our services using only SpringBoot without Liberty.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The main advantages to using Open Liberty or WebSphere Liberty with SpringBoot rather than a standalone Spring Boot jar are smaller overall image sizes, reduced container registry push sizes, lower memory footprint and increased throughput. It's a bit of an older article, but this is summarized pretty well in https://developer.ibm.com/articles/modernize-and-optimize-spring-boot-applications/

Comment: Additionally article that shows performance advantage in using OpenLiberty instead of embedded Tomcat [How does Open Liberty’s performance compare to other cloud-native Java runtimes](https://openliberty.io/blog/2022/10/17/memory-footprint-throughput-update.html)